# Cmake/gRPC - Unable to find OpenSSL on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, openssl, grpc

I want to use gRPC library for my project.
Here is my CmakeLists.txt:

```
target_link_libraries(${LibName} PUBLIC
        ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}
        asio
        threads
        fmt
        utf8cpp
        mysql
        zlib
        g3dlib
        curl
        rapidjson
        uuid
        gRPC::grpc++
)
```

If I remove the line `gRPC::grpc++` all is fine. However I get the following error when I try to run cmake:

```
CMake Error at Source/Common/CMakeLists.txt:57 (add_library):
  Target "Common" links to target "OpenSSL::SSL" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at Source/Common/CMakeLists.txt:57 (add_library):
  Target "Common" links to target "OpenSSL::Crypto" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?
```

I have openssl installed on my Mac. Take a look:

```
☁  ~  openssl version
LibreSSL 2.8.3
☁  ~  which openssl
/usr/bin/openssl
```

If I add `find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)` in my CmakeLists I get this error:

```
CMake Error at /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenSSL (missing: OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: @drescherjm yes I explained this one in the question.

Comment: Install OpenSSL library. What you show is openssl executable, gRPC doesn't care.